# What is the output voltage of this OP amp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I'm trying to solve (b):

[image]

This is what the solution manual gives as an answer:

[image]

However, this seems a little off to me. I tried using nodal analysis to solve this problem and I get the following result.

[image]

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Their answer is correct: http://imgur.com/aRTEYDQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my mistake. In my step 1, I write: 0.2 = -vc/40 + vo/12, but it should actually be 0.2 = -vc/40 **-** vo/12.

:SSSSS

Comment: You probably mean 0.2 = -vc/40 - v**o**  /12 =  -vo/20 - vo/12. So vo = -1.5 from [that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.2+%3D+-v%2F20+-+v%2F12).